# How would I map an @Entity with a hbm.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I in a situation where I need to override some fields in a @Entity class but I can't edit the class. It just so happens that this @Entity class is mapped in a way that I don't think it's possible to partially override it. I was wondering what would be the steps to overriding this class completely or maybe partially if possible.

The class:
[org.broadleafcommerce.profile.core.domain.AddressImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.broadleafcommerce/broadleaf-profile/2.0.0-GA/org/broadleafcommerce/profile/core/domain/AddressImpl.java)

I've used a hbm.xml and a orm.xml but I'm not exactly sure how to configure them properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book Pro JPA 2 : Mastering the Java Persistence API notes:

> The metadata-complete attribute is an attribute on the entity,
>   mapped-superclass, and embeddable elements. If specified, all
>   annotations on the specified class and on any fields or properties in
>   the class will be ignored, and only the metadata in the mapping file
>   will be considered as the set of metadata for the class. When
>   metadata-complete is enabled, the same rules that we applied to
>   annotated entities will still apply when using XML-mapped entities.
>   For example, the identifier must be mapped, and all relationships must
>   be specified with their corresponding cardinality mappings inside the
>   entity element.

So you will need an entry in your orm.xml like the below, adding **all** other persistent attributes as required (partial override is not possible).

```
<entity-mappings>
    <entity class="com.Foo" metadata-complete="true">
        <table name="FOO"/>
        <attributes>
            <id name="id"/>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```